# The program does not crash neither executes completely

Tags: loops, c++11, random

it has been a few hours since I am dealing with this issue. I was wondering if someone could point out what am I doing wrong, and if possible - how to fix it. Essentially, I am simply trying to generate `n` number of object pairs and store them into a `vector<pair<Foo, Foo>>`. The algorithm involves random number generator. I use STL `<random>` and its components like `m19937`, `uniform_real_distribution` and `uniform_int_distribution`. Below is the simplified version of what I am trying to do representing the case I got at hand. The second loop always cuts short. However, I fail to see the reason why. Essentially, I never get to see the program execute completely. The last two messages never show.

**program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <utility>

// utility
using std::pair;

// random
using std::mt19937;
using std::uniform_int_distribution;
using std::uniform_real_distribution;

// iostream
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// vector
using std::vector;

class Event{
private:
  double x, y;
public:
  Event(const double X, const double Y);
};

Event::Event(const double X, const double Y): x(X), y(Y){}

int main(){
  cout << "Initializing storage..." << endl;
  vector<Event> population;
  vector<pair<Event,Event>> selection;

  cout << "Initializing necessary member variables..." << endl;
  const unsigned int SEED = 14112017;
  const unsigned int MAX_ITERATIONS = 10000;

  const double MIN = 1;
  const double MAX = 10000;

  mt19937 engine(SEED);

  cout << "Generating the initial population..." << endl;
  uniform_real_distribution<> real_distribution(MIN, MAX);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; ++i){
    double x = real_distribution(engine);
    double y = real_distribution(engine);

    Event event(x, y);

    population.push_back(event);
  }
  cout << "Success! The initial population has been generated successfully" << endl;

  population.shrink_to_fit();

  cout << "Starting the selection process..." << endl;
  unsigned int random = 0;
  uniform_int_distribution<> int_distribution(MIN, MAX);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; ++i){
    random = int_distribution(engine);
    Event event_x = population.at(random);

    random = int_distribution(engine);
    Event event_y = population.at(random);

    pair<Event, Event> bound(event_x, event_y);

    selection.push_back(bound);
  }
  cout << "Success! The selection process has been completed successfully" << endl;

  selection.shrink_to_fit();

  cout << "population size: " << population.size() << endl;
  cout << "selection size: " << selection.size() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I compile the above using cygwins C++ compiler, and I execute the code in command-prompt. The OS is Windows 10 x64. The box has 32 GB memory.

Comment: You should have gotten a [hint](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/822f8e9a73ec402d) when executing the program.

Comment: I execute using `-std=c++11` no hints or errors are displayed. I got following flags set `-std=c++11 -Wall -g`

Comment: That is unfortunate. But the program has no undefined behavior as far as I can see, it just throws an unhandled exception, so running it under a debugger should pause the program at the line where the out-of-bounds access happens.

Comment: @nwp Indeed the reason is right there in the error message. "__n (**which is 10000**) is greater than or equal to size (which is 10000)".

Comment: @RaymondChen what does that actually mean? I am fairly new to C++, I would appreciate a bit more information

Comment: The size is 10000. Asking for the element at index 10000 is out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uniform_int_distribution`s constructor is as follows:

```
explicit uniform_int_distribution( IntType a = 0,
    IntType b = std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max() );
```

By default, it returns an integer which covers *all* positive values of that type. The range *includes* the value of the second parameter. If it wouldn't, it would be cumbersome to specify we want all positive integers.

<strike>[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/uniform_int_distribution) does not document it, but the C++ standard does:</strike> [Thanks @Cubbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289571/the-program-does-not-crash-neither-executes-completely/47290014#comment81541818_47290014)
This is documented [on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), or in the C++ standard:

> **26.5.8.2.1  Class template uniform_int_distribution**  [rand.dist.uni.int]
>   1  A uniform_int_distribution random number
>   distribution produces random integers i, a ≤ i ≤ b, distributed
>   according to the constant discrete probability function
>   *[...]*
>   `// constructors and reset functions
>   explicit uniform_int_distribution(IntType a = 0, IntType b = numeric_limits<IntType>::max());`

Here:

```
  uniform_int_distribution<> int_distribution(MIN, MAX);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; ++i){
    random = int_distribution(engine);
    Event event_x = population.at(random);

    random = int_distribution(engine);
    Event event_y = population.at(random);
```

`random` can take the value `MAX`, which is out of the bounds of the `population` vector.

Comment: This has helped me, essentially the assignment to `random` has exceeded the boundary of the container. Therefore, when `random` would be set to `MAX`, the next instruction `populate.at(random)` would be invalid! :) Thank you +1 and accepting the answer.